# Importing Eclipse project (with third-party libraries) to Android Studio 1.0

Tags: eclipse, import, android-studio, libgdx, admob

I have developed an Eclipse project (a game based on libgdx). I have included LibGdx library, Facebook SDK and google-play-services_lib. My game uses facebook "share" function and AdMob ads.

After developing it, I made documentation for this project, and I included the link for downloading  Eclipse+adt for my client. But when he had followed to this link, he was forced to download Android Studio, not Eclipse. And now I don't know how to import this project to Android Studio.

I tried to import, it was imported well with right project structure.But when I click "Run" button, there are many errors occurs. All third-party libraries are unknown for Android Studio, many classes are  not found, etc. I don't know how to setup Android Studio for LibGdx and AdMob (google play services).

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the 3rd party libraries as dependencies in your `build.gradle` file.
The process is explained very well [in the documentation](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html).

Comment: Yep.  Google also has a doc that shows how this works for AdMob and Play Services: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/quick-start#configuring_gradle